# An algorithm for a number divisible to n

Tags: c#

At first user gives a number (**n**) to program, for example **5**.
the program must find the smallest number that can be divided to **n** (5).
and this number can only consist of digits 0 and 9 not any other digits.

for example if user gives **5** to program.
numbers that can be divided to 5 are:

```
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, ..., 85, 90, 95, ...
```

but 90 here is the smallest number that can be divided to 5 and also consist of digits (0 , 9). so answer for 5 must be 90.
and answer for 9 is 9, because it can be divided to 9 and consist of digit (9).

my code

```
string a = txtNumber.Text;
Int64 x = Convert.ToInt64(a);
Int64 i ,j=1,y=x;
bool t = false;
for (i = x + 1; t == false; i++)
{
    if (i % 9 == 0 && i % 10 == 0 && i % x == 0)
    {
        j = i;
        for (; (i /= 10) != 0; )
        {
            i /= 10;
            if (i == 0)
                t = true;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
lblAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(j);
```

Comment: i didnt get your question

Comment: for example you give 5,answer should be coefficient of 5 and should be made of digits 0 and 9.

Comment: is there any problem with the current code, if there is any problem then please mention that in your post.

Comment: Is that the number will only contain `0` & `9` not any other digit or other digits are allowed.....

Comment: Why is the answer not 0? It's divisible by 5, and doesn't contain any digits other than 0 and 9. Or must both 0 and 9 be part of the output? In that case, would the output for 3 also be 90?

Comment: @dbw only 0 and 9 are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code for console, and i used goto command however it is not prefered but i could not write it with only for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace main
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your number");
        Int64 x = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
        Int64 y, j, i, k, z = x;
        x = x + 5;
    loop:
        x++;
        for (i = 0, y = x; y != 0; i++)
            y /= 10;

        for (j = x, k = i; k != 0; j /= 10, k--)
        {
            if (j % 10 != 9)
                if (j % 10 != 0)
                    goto loop;
        }
        if (x % z != 0)
            goto loop;
        Console.WriteLine("answer:{0}",x);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy to go purely functional then this works:

```
Func<IEnumerable<long>> generate = () =>
{
    Func<long, IEnumerable<long>> extend =
        x => new [] { x * 10, x * 10 + 9 };

    Func<IEnumerable<long>, IEnumerable<long>> generate2 = null;
    generate2 = ns =>
    {
        var clean = ns.Where(n => n > 0).ToArray();
        return clean.Any()
            ? clean.Concat(generate2(clean.SelectMany(extend)))
            : Enumerable.Empty<long>();
    };

    return generate2(new[] { 9L, });
};

Func<long, long?> f = n =>
    generate()
        .Where(x => x % n == 0L)
        .Cast<long?>()
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

So rather than iterate through all possible values and test for `0` & `9` and divisibility, this just generates only numbers with `0` & `9` and then only tests for visibility. It is much faster this way.

I can call it like this:

```
var result = f(5L); // 90L
result = f(23L); //990909L
result = f(123L); //99999L
result = f(12321L); //90900999009L
result = f(123212L); //99909990090000900L
result = f(117238L); //990990990099990990L
result = f(1172438L); //null == No answer
```

These results are super fast. `f(117238L)` returns a result on my computer in 138ms.

Comment: I have revised my answer with a super fast function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple code

```
int inputNumber = 5/*Or every other number, you can get this number from input.*/;
int result=1;
for (int i = 1; !IsOk(result,inputNumber); i++)
{
    result = i*inputNumber;
}
Print(result);
```

IsOk method is here:

```
bool IsOk(int result, int inputNumber)
{
    if(result%inputNumber!=0)
        return false;
    if(result.ToString().Replace("9",string.Empty).Replace("0",string.Empty).Length!=0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please take your test data that cause my code produce wrong answer.

Comment: Your code, exactly as it stands, produces the result `0`, not `90` as expected.

Comment: That's right, variable 'i' most initialize by '1' no '0'. Code reclaimed, test it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48798/discussion-between-merta-and-enigmativity)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
string a = txtNumber.Text;
Int64 x = Convert.ToInt64(a);

int counter;
for (counter = 1; !isValid(x * counter); counter++)
{
}
lblAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(counter*x);
```

code above works by searching multiple of `x` incrementally until `result` that satisfy criteria : "*consist of only 0 and or 9 digits*" found. By searching only multiple of `x`, it is guaranteed to be divisible by `x`. So the rest is checking validity of result candidate, in this case using following `isValid()` function :

```
private static bool isValid(int number)
{
    var lastDigit = number%10;

    //last digit is invalid, return false
    if (lastDigit != 0 & lastDigit != 9) return false;

    //last digit is valid, but there is other digit(s)
    if(number/10 >= 1) 
    {
        //check validity of digit(s) before the last
        return isValid(number/10);
    }

    //last digit is valid, and there is no other digit. return true
    return true;
}
```

About strange empty `for` loop in snippet above, it is just syntactic sugar, to make the code a bit shorter. It is equal to following `while` loop :

```
counter = 1;
while(!isValid(input*counter))
{
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: I got error "has some invalid arguments" for "!isValid(x * counter)".and how for loop is empty but has {}?

Comment: about `for` loop, check my update. About the error, I don't get that error, working fine here. `isValid` function in this sample expect `int` argument, make sure `x` and `counter` are both `int` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

My first solution has very bad performance, because of converting a number to string and looking for characters '9' and '0'.

**New solution:**

My new solution has very good performance and is a technical approach since of using Breadth-first search(BFS).

**Algorithm of this solution:**

For every input number, test 9, if it is answer print it, else add 2 child numbers (90 & 99) to queue, and continue till finding answer.

```
int inputNumber = 5;/*Or every other number, you can get this number from input.*/
long result;
var q = new Queue<long>();
q.Enqueue(9);
while (true)
{
    result = q.Dequeue();
    if (result%inputNumber == 0)
    {
        Print(result);
        break;
    }
    q.Enqueue(result*10);
    q.Enqueue(result*10 + 9);
}
```

Trace of number creation:

9

90,99

900,909,990,999

9000,9009,9090,9099,9900,9909,9990,9999

.
.
.